# Who's doing the computing on a remote folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, nfs, shared-folders

When you're working with a remote folder, shared directory, or anything along those lines in Windows and you copy/move files, create a zip directory, or something along those lines on the server's folder from the remote client computer, **which computer is doing the work?** Is it the client? Or is it the server?

Obviously, one would assume it's the client, but I would just like to know for sure and possibly get an explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the client.

It might help if you imagine working on paper documents on a desk.
**You** (as in, your computer) is doing the work.

Now you take some really long wooden sticks and start working on the desk next to you (the shared folder). You are still doing all the work.

Comment: I'd like to add that the server is doing a minuscule amount of work (processing the active connection, logging it, perhaps some bandwidth related activities), but all of this adds up to a negligible amount.

Comment: Yes. I could change it to 'a desktop with your own secretary to hand you the files so you can work on them' and 'a remote desktop with its own secretary behind a phone line, who will hand/read you your files so that you can work on them).

Comment: Or we could just say that your computer you are sitting at does the work work, but the other computer still has to access the files to send it to you and write it back when you're done